# WP Rest API with vue.js

Tags: wordpress, rest, vue.js

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, still  pretty noob at vue js so that might be the problem. 
The problem is that it does not display anything. I got it to work with older vue version with a bit different code, but yeah...

```
var App = Vue.extend({});

var postList = Vue.extend({
  template:'#post-list-template',
  data: function(){
    return {
        posts: ''
    }
},

      mounted: function(){
      posts = this.$http.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10');

      posts.get(function(posts){
          this.$set('posts', posts);
      })
  }
 });


  var router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
  { path: '/', component: postList}
]
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>'
});
```

HTML is here if that makes things a bit easier to understand :

```
       <div class="container-fluid projects" id="projects">

           <h1 class="text-center project-heading">Projects</h1>

             <div class="white-wrap">

           <div id="app">

             <router-view></router-view>

            </div>

        </div>


            <template id="post-list-template">
             <div class="container">

                <div class="post-list">

                   <article v-for="post in posts">

                      <div class="post-content">

                       <h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
                             {{ post.id }}
                           </div>

                  </article>

                  </div>

                 </div>

           </template>


         </div>
```

Comment: Could you share what you're expecting that code to do and what happens instead in an [edit]?

Comment: **why haven't you listed the problem you're having?**

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my problem:

```
    var postLists = Vue.component('post-list',{
       template:'#post-list-template',
       data: function () {
         return {
               posts:'',
          }
        },
     mounted:function () {
          this.$http.get('./wp-json/wp/v2/posts').then(response => {

        // get body data
        this.posts = response.body;

        this.posts.forEach(function (){

        } );

       }, response => {
         console.log('Not Found');
       });
   }


   });

  //router
   var router = new VueRouter({

   routes: [
       { path: '', component: postLists },
      ]
    });

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router: router,

    });
```